# Proving Finite Exponential Sum $\sum_{k\in\{0,r,...,N-r\}} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi ikl}{N}\right)=\sqrt{N/r}\text{ if l is integer multiple of N/r} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum, quantum-computation

I saw a mathematical expression in a Quantum Computation Textbook that states

$$\sum_{k\in\{0,r,2r,...,N-r\}} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi ikl}{N}\right) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{N/r} &
 \text{ if } l \text{ is an integer multiple of } N/r, \\\\0 &\text{  otherwise}\end{cases} $$

I know how to sum a geometric series but I can't see why this is the case. By setting $r=1$ and $l = pN$ for some integer $p$, I get the result to be $N$ instead of $\sqrt{N}$. Can someone explain?

Additionally $N$ is an integer multiple of $r$.

Snapshot of Textbook
[image]

Comment: Is the index set for the summation correct?  Should the last element perhaps be $Nr-r$?

Comment: @saulspatz No. Its written as such but I had added additional information upon further checking.

Comment: Unless $N$ is a multiple of $r$, it's not clear to me what the index set is supposed to be, since it seems like it's supposed to consist of multiples of $r$.  Your example is correct when $r=1$, however.  It looks to me like there's some kind of typo.  Maybe someone can figure it out if you give more context.  That's unlikely to be me, however, since I know nothing about quantum mechanics.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes $N$ is a multiple of $r$ as stated in the Edit.